# How to manage multi-language React Native apps?

Tags: react-native, mobile, internationalization, cross-platform, multilingual

I work for a small Startup and we ran into an issue. We already launched our React Native app in multiple countries and for those countries we use the same repository.. Currently we are using multiple main branches such as main-cz, main-en ... but this setup doesn't really work anymore since the team is growing and this setup leads many errors.. Originally we wanted the different countries into one repository because most of the code is shared but we realised that we have different setups now in different countries but still not that different to manage multiple repositories. How do you guys manage a multi language react native app on Github? If you have any experience how to manage apps/workflow properly please let me know.

We would like to create an easily manageable multi-lang react-native workflow

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage multi-language you can use this package [react-native-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localization). It is easy to install and easy to use. You can find more information at the link.